# I'm stuck with my python csv homework

Tags: python, csv

When I run the code the first time it works. When I run it a second time, it can't find the csv file until I replace it. I don't know why this is.

I would also like to sort the times with the fastest at the top.

```
    def read_class_data():
    import csv
    driver=[]
    team=[]
    input_file = open("E:\Advanced Higher Computing\Racing.csv","r")
    data = csv.reader(input_file)
    print ("driver: ", driver)
    for eachline in data:
        driver.append(eachline[0])
        team.append(eachline[1])
    input_file.close()
    return driver, team

def register():
    time=[]*6
    for i in range(6):
        temptime = float(input("What is your best time?"))
        while temptime < 0:
            print("Time cannot be less than 0.")
            temptime = float(input("What is your best time?"))
        time.append(temptime)
    return time

def write_class_data(dr, tm, time):
    import csv
    output_file = open("E:\Advanced Higher Computing\Racing.csv","w")
    data = csv.writer(output_file)
    for i in range(len(time)):
        data.writerow([dr[i], tm[i], time[i]])
    output_file.close()

dr, tm = read_class_data()
time = register()
write_class_data(dr, tm, time)
```

Comment: The error message contains a line number. You might consider adding it to your question.

Comment: We can't do much without the actual error message and line number, unless you actually provide as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Good point - sorry . Have added now - thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to get the names for driver and team from a csv file and I'm trying to allow the user to write times into the csv file.

Comment: After `driver=[]*6`, do `print driver` and see what you created. You cannot take the index of an empty list.

Comment: on lines 9,10: `driver[loop] = eachline[0]`, 
`team[loop] = eachline[1]` you can't assign column data to list indices that don't yet exist, but you can append() or insert() to the list. try `driver.append(eachline[0])`, `team.append(eachline[1])`

Comment: Thank you @downshift. The program will now run and ask users for six times. However, these times replace all of the data inside of the csv file.

Comment: @ roganjosh The 'print (driver)' line prints '[]'.

Comment: @Bennana59, that's because you are writing the new data to the same file you are reading from. You can't edit columns in the same csv file. You'll either need to write to a new (different) csv file, or you could save all the rows in the file and re-write them with the user input back into the same file.

Comment: It seems like your original csv file has two columns of data, the `driver`, and `team` lists. Do you want the times to written to the 3rd column in the csv file?

Comment: @downshift yes please

Comment: @Bennana59, ok, check if this code works http://dpaste.com/1DZVRZK

Comment: Thank you very much @downshift This is amazing. You have answered my question.

Comment: Great to hear @Bennana59, good luck and cheers mate!

Comment: When I run the code the first time it works. When I run it a second time, it can't find the csv file until I replace it. Do you @downshift what the problem here is?

Comment: @Bennana59, Oops I apologize, If you are using the code I linked to, I changed the name of the `Racing.csv` location, you may need to change those lines back to the original path in your usb drive, i.e. `input_file = open("E:\Advanced Higher Computing\Racing.csv","r")` and `output_file = open("E:\Advanced Higher Computing\Racing.csv","w", newline="")`

Comment: @downshift I changed it but the problem still persists.

Comment: @downshift I'm wandering if there is a way (obviously there will be) to sort the times with the fastest time at the top.

Comment: Sure, we can figure out a way to do that. But first, is the csv file still getting removed after you run the code a second time? We'll want to fix that problem first

Comment: if you want to sort the times with the fastest time at the top, and then write it all back to `Racing.csv` file, we'll probably want to convert the `driver` and `team` information into `dictionary` data-types so that it is easier to sort the times and still keep the times lined up with the driver and teams.

Answer (score -1):

You have many problems in your code, but let's just look at the first function

```
def read_class_data():
    import csv
    driver=[]*6
    teams=[]*6
    input_file = open("E:\Advanced Higher Computing\Racing.csv","r")
    data = csv.reader(input_file)
    loop = 1
    for eachline in data:
        driver[loop] = eachline[0]
        team[loop] = eachline[1]
        loop = loop + 1
        inputfile.close
    return driver, teams
```

First,

```
driver =[]*6
```

doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It creates an empty array, i.e. one of length zero.

That's actually where you are getting the error. On the first pass through the loop, `loop` has the value 1 and you are trying to assign to `driver[1]` ... which doesn't exist, because `len(driver) == 0`.

Next, setting `loop` to 1 shows that you are thinking Python list indices are 1-based. They're not: Python uses zero-based indexing.

You need to `append` to a list to add new data, so your loop might look more like

```
for eachline in data:
    driver.append(eachline[0])
    team.append(eachline[1])
```

Next, you have a call to `inputfile.close` in the loop. You actually aren't calling it because you don't have the needed parentheses. It should be `inputfile.close()`.

But if it was, your loop would crash on the second pass, because the file was already closed on the previous pass. You need to move that line out of the loop.

Finally, you should be using context-managers anyway (i.e. `with`) so the function ends up something like

```
def read_class_data():
    import csv
    driver = []
    teams = []

    with open("E:\Advanced Higher Computing\Racing.csv","r") as input_file:
        data = csv.reader(input_file)

        for eachline in data:
            driver.append(eachline[0])
            team.append(eachline[1])

    return driver, teams
```

Comment: This looks good but my program still has the same errors. I've been trying to apply this style of code to the rest of my program still doesn't work.